# Unable to retrieve id from neo4j in some scenario's

Tags: java, neo4j

I am very new to neo4j so please don't mind if my question seems a little vague.

> My scenario is:
>
> 1. Start a new session and a transaction.
> 2. Create a node 'A' in that transaction and to tx.run() and return the id of the node.
> 3. Create a node 'B' in that transaction and to tx.run() and return the id of the node.
> 4. Create another node 'C' and create an edge between nodes 'A' and 'C' and return the node C id.

**For the step 2 and 3 I'm able to receive the id's from neo4j, but for step 4 I unable to retrieve the ID from the node.**

*For step 2 or 3 cypher's are like*

```
MERGE (u:USER{NAME:'user1', UNIQUEID:'user1X'})
RETURN id(u)
```

Assume it returns id as'2'

*For step 4 cypher's are like*

```
START u = node(2)
MERGE (r:RELATION{NAME:'rel1', UNIQUEID:'rel1X'})
MERGE (u)-[:BELONGSTO]-(r)
RETURN id(r)
```

the Neo4j Version: 3.2.3 and queries are fired using Jcypher in java. Please update in comments if u need any more information.

Comment: Are you sure that `2` is the native ID of node `A`?

Comment: Yes I checked...even I tried to fire some random queries during debug, that won't return the ids either but data is being added to the neo4j

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there was something wrong with the neo4j instance. I restarted and everything worked fine.